# Display text returned from json post call

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, json

I have the following javascript:

```
$.post("/Authenticated/DeletePage/" + PageId);
showStatus("Page deleted...", 10000);
```

I would like to instead pass showStatus() text that is returned by the $.post() call, rather than hardcoded text.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post("/Authenticated/DeletePage/" + PageId, function(data){
   showStatus( data + " deleted...", 10000);
});
```

and for JSON

```
$.getJSON("/Authenticated/DeletePage/" + PageId, function(data){
   showStatus( data.pageName + " deleted...", 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/Authenticated/DeletePage/" + PageId, function(JSONdata) {
  showStatus(JSONdata.Name + " deleted...", 10000); //This is just to show you, signature is different
});
```

See jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/